# Insert formula from different table based on table cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to have a cell formula based on a formula stored in a separate table/sheet based on another cell of the same row.

Sheet "values" table has a column "Type". Based on the value in Type, the Formula in the next column should be inserted. The formula is in the sheet "rules" with the same type reference.

[image: Formula based on Type]

[image: Formula reference]

There will be multiple type values, so writing a complex if formula is nasty.

Any tips on how to achieve this?
Thanks.

Comment: This is just a simple example. The formula is much more complex.
So it is saved as a TEXT in the rules sheet. The VLOOKUP inserts the text, but doesn't convert it into a formula.

Comment: To convert you need VBA then not sure how you will convert a formula using another formula as it is in TEXT Format.

Comment: Is there the opposit of FORMULATEXT()? FORMULATEXT() shows the formula as a text. But I would need to convert the formula as text into a real formula.

Comment: I am not sure, what I am sure about is you need VBA here

Comment: Are the formulas only different in some constants - or are they calculating in a different way, e.g. Rule 1 is multiplying a constant value, Rule 3 adds some constants etc.

Comment: The only way to write a formula into a cell is to use macros, either VBA or XLM4 `FORMULA()` macro-function; Excel relies on the formulas to recalculate the sheet, so if you change a formula, everything need to be recalculated...

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with VBA:

```
Dim rule As String
Dim FindRowNumber As Long

rule = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 2).Value

Set FindRow = Worksheets("rules").Range("A:A").Find(What:=rule, LookIn:=xlValues)
FindRowNumber = FindRow.Row

Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 3).FormulaLocal = Worksheets("rule").Cells(FindRowNumber, 2).Value
```

This works in my Excel 64bit. But on another Computer with Excel 2016 32 bit, I get a runtime error 1004 on the FormulaLocal line.

Does anyone know why this works in 64bit excel, but not in 32bit?!?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).